# Add 2 numbers leetcode: why is reversing input not possible?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at LeetCode problem [2. Add Two Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/):

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.
>
> ```
> Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
> Output: [7,0,8]
> Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
> ```

This is the code I tried with:

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
  l1.reverse();
  l2.reverse();
  let l1temp = '';
  let l2temp = '';
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
    l1temp.concat(l1[i]);
  }

  parseInt(l1temp);

  for (let i = 0; i < l2.length; i++) {
    l2temp.concat(l2[i]);
  }

  parseInt(l2temp);

  var hello = l2temp + l1temp;
  hello.split("").reverse().join("")
  array = hello.split('')
  return array
};
```

When I submit this code on LeetCode, it gives a runtime error on line 2 saying that `reverse` isn't a function. I don't understand why `reverse` would be a problem here?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: _"btw i have syntaxed it properly using tab..."_ -> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: By the sound of your function name, `l1` and `l2` are numbers. Numbers don't have a `reverse()` method (nor do strings)

Comment: what are inputs to `addTwoNumbers` ?

Comment: `l1` and `l2` are not arrays. They are linked lists!

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/ this is the thing im working on. l1 and l2 are arrays and the inputs are l1 and l2

Comment: if they are linked lists, how do i convert them to arrays?

Comment: It clearly states *"You are given two non-empty **linked lists**"*. You shouldn't convert them to arrays. The challenge is to work with linked lists and not use arrays at all. The code challenge explains what the structure of a linked list is, and the template code you were presented with included in comments the definition of the `ListNode` class. That is information you need to use.

Comment: Also note the description states that the input can contain up to 100 digits, so converting the input into two numbers will run into precision issues.

Answer (score 3):

You mistakenly thought that the function would be called with arrays as arguments. But this code challenge starts by saying:

> You are given two non-empty **linked lists**...

They are not arrays, as also can be seen from the image that is presented in that code challenge, and the template code that you got to start with. It includes this constructor in a comment block:

> ```
> function ListNode(val, next) {
>     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
>     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
> }
> ```

This is information you should use: the arguments that you get are instances of `ListNode`, so they will be objects with `val` and `next` properties (or be `null`). The idea is *not* to convert those linked lists to arrays (as that would unnecessarily use extra space), but to do the job without arrays.

Also be aware that your function must return a linked list, so you should really familiarise yourself with that data structure.

There are several Q&A on this site that deal with this LeetCode question, and I myself have also posted answers. But the challenge is of course to solve this without looking at a solution. So refrain from following these links until you are completely desperate :)

- [adding linked lists #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049408/5459839)
- [adding linked lists #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70926341/5459839)

Comment: "as that would unnecessarily use extra space". I do not think that this is the main problem for OP's approach.  Rather, the parseint call will not return the correct number once the input gets large enough that the ulp is more than 1.

Comment: @Taemyr, well we know the main problem starts earlier, as they have noted in their question. The arguments are not arrays. My mention of arrays relates to their comment *"if they are linked lists, how do i convert them to arrays?"*, and my answer is: don't. The idea is *not* to use extra space.

Comment: Well, op wants to convert to array in order to iterate the over it, so that he can create a stringifued number, that he can pass to parseint.  It is true that he can bypass the need for an array by iterating over the list, but the approach is still fundamentally flawed given that the end result of that iteration is not useful.

Comment: I get you, @Taemyr, but the question was about why `reverse` gave an error. My answer does not intend to further scrutenise the rest of their code. I mention arrays in reaction to their comment to convert linked lists to arrays. If you want to analyse the rest of their code, and defend the idea to convert to arrays, then this could be useful as part of an answer you post here.